# Какую библиотеку можно использовать для визуализации на C#?

Tags: c#, 3d, поиск-библиотек

Задача стоит такая, нужно визуализировать работу одной из библиотек, над которой работаю я. Визуализировать мне нужно наборы вертикальных граней, которые заданы четырьмя точками в пространстве (то есть визуализация должна быть в 3D). Так же нужно визуализировать набор точек, некоторую сетку, каждая точка так же задана тремя координатами. И в зависимости от одного свойства окрашивать точку либо в красный, либо в зеленый цвет. Граней много, координаты большие относительно. Смотрел на библиотеку OpenTK, думал ее заюзать. Решил все таки здесь спросить, может у кого такая же ситуация была. Желательно чтобы лицензия была MIT.
[image: Пример]

Что то вроде этого нужно.

Comment: Godot? Он как раз MIT.

Comment: @Qwer я совсем не слышал про него, это какой-то фреймворк для игр?

Comment: @Qwer жирноват для столь простой задачи

Comment: @andreymal посоветуете что-нибудь еще? Просто очень много всего, а я вообще никогда не рисовал ничего, тем более в 3D

Comment: @Qwer я так понимаю его надо отдельно скачивать, как движок по сути. Мне нужна библиотека, я ее интегрирую в проект, там внутри начну тестить разработанную либу. Нужно чтобы просто открывалось окно и все это визуализировалось там

Comment: А показанная картинка в целом-то даже не 3D, можно вручную координаты всех этих линий на плоскости рассчитать, если не лень

Comment: @andreymal это пример, по сути нужно в 3D. На вход множество объектов Edge в которых есть координаты. И вот по этим координатам нужно строить эти грани.

Comment: Я бы вообще `Unity 3D` предложил, но чисто для отрисовки это и правда слишком. Наверняка проще вообще какой-нибудь `JS` фреймворк для этого взять.

Comment: @CrazyElf что то вроде cesium? А как его прикрутить к проекту?

Comment: SDL + OpenGL Но придётся разбираться, решение не из коробки. Если надо чтобы было два отдельных приложения - твоё_приложение + вьюер - я бы попробовал написать вьюер, используя Godot, и связать их, например, через анонимные каналы или ещё как (гугли "C# межпроцессное взаимодействие").

Comment: @Андрей Да полно библиотек, я просто не специалист. Я бы смотрел в сторону того, чтобы из бэка отдавать данные в `json`, а на фронте `JS` библиотекой рисовать по нему фигуры. Это как-то по-современному.